# Calling DynamoDB BatchGetItem from Lambda has >1000ms latency. Is it normal?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, latency

I'm doing a POC to find out how fast DynamoDB is. The example problem I'm trying to solve is the following:

I have a 100 keys on the input. For each key I have to look up associated info. The associated info for each key has ~8kB.

I've stored the keys with their associated info to DynamoDB, table `test_table`, set the capacity to on-demand mode. I'm getting the info from an AWS Lambda function. The table and the Lambda are in the same region (EU Frankfurt). Here is the code sample for getting info for the given key list:

```
key_list = [
    'key0',
    # ...
    'key99'
]
dynamo_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response = dynamo_client.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems={
        'test_table': {
            'Keys': [
                {
                    'key': {'S': k}
                } for k in key_list
            ],
            'ConsistentRead': False
        }
    }
)
```

I always run the Lambda a few times to make sure it's warmed up. When I did this test for the first time, it took ~2000ms. My expectations are to get this in ~500ms. Things I did to speed it up:

- Increased Lambda memory from 1GB to max (~3GB). I got to ~1300ms. On Lambda, with more memory, you get more bandwidth, so I guess this is why it got faster.
- I've provisioned big read capacity in DynamoDB (1000), to see if auto-scaling isn't slowing things down. I saw no measurable effect.
- I checked CloudWatch metrics for the DynamoDB table, the latency there is ~180ms. This is pretty good, so it looks like it's not a DynamoDB issue.
- I installed aws x-ray sdk to check if there's something slowing things down on the lambda side. The `batch_get_item` call is taking ~1250ms out of ~1300ms, the rest is lambda initialization. So My guess was that the slowdown must be happening somewhere between the Lambda and DynamoDB
- I've put the Lambda into a VPC and used a Service Endpoint for DynamoDB - it had no measurable effect.
- I've put the code to a EC2 instance with as much network bandwidth as I could get (100 Gigabit) and it took ~900ms. Still not good.

So my guess is that the bottleneck is somewhere between the Lambda and the DynamoDB table.

I haven't tried DAX, because it involves some extra costs for the cluster, plus I'm not sure it would help, as DAX promises to speed things up on the DynamoDB side, which doesn't seem to be the bottleneck.

My question is: Is it somewhat normal that getting ~8MB from a DynamoDB to a Lambda takes >1000ms? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what read capacity have you provisioned the DynamoDB with? AWS SDKs can do weird things with retries and I'm wondering if that is what is happening here. For that query, your read capacity should be set to atleast 100, maybe 150 as the expected individual response is approximately 8KB.

Comment: Good question, I forgot to mention this - I've edited the question - tried both on-demand and generous provisioned read capacity and saw no speed up. 
The cloudwatch charts didn't show any errors or retries.